# App submittion details - apple appstore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

If I created an application for some social network, do i need to give username and password for tests when I submit my application in itunesconnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you should provide test username and password or video presentation.

They should check the content of your app somehow.

Comment: How to send them video presentation?

Comment: Share it somewhere... Youtube?

Comment: Good luck =) I suggest to use `DisplayRecorder` (in Cydia Store). It's perfect